# FC New Dawn - set controls on same button in helicopter, vehicle or on foot?

Tags: keyboard, far-cry-new-dawn

I just bought New Dawn and i want do easy thing. Switch button "C" with "CTRL" "on foot" (there is key settings on foot, in vehicle and helicopter) so i want crouch with ctrl key and use medkit with c key.

But if i change C button on foot is C button automatic unbinded in helicopter and vehicle... So i was try set C button on vehicle and helicopter to his default function but can't... Only if i unbind C on foot key... WTF?!

If i set C function as was his default setting on vehicle and helicopter (there i can set one C key to 2 different functions) still i can't set this key to use medkit BUT on picture is not purple letter so game know there "on foot" is this key unbinded but still you can't set.. Only if you unbind C on vehicle and heli... It is insane :)

So there is not way to set one key to 3 different actions - on foot, vehicle and helicopter?! Is this joke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i figuret it out.

Change any keybind in control setting... this action will create new file with name:  `hidinputremapper.xml` in `Documents\My Games\Far Cry 5` path. After that open this file and paste to it this code:

```
<Root>
    <remap name="crouch" key="kb.LCONTROL" />
    <remap name="heal" key="kb.C" />
</Root>
```

And it will change ONLY heal to C key and crouch to control key...

And you can bind key action only on foot even though is used in helicopter and/or in vehicle...